# How to iterate a JSON array using Mustache

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I'm new to JSON and mustache.  I'm trying to iterate an array that I've created using Mustache and I'm running into some issues.  My code looks like this:

```
var shows=[         
        {"title":"Strawberry Shortcake","description":"A show about a cake","video":"none","category":"chilren"},
        {"title":"Vanilla Ice","description":"A show about a ice","video":"none","category":"adult"}
];

var template="{{#shows}}{{.}}{{/shows}}";

var html=Mustache.render(template,shows);

document.write(html);
```

Comment: Please explain those *issues*. And what do you expect.

Comment: You've written "interate" instead of "iterate". I can't edit it myself since it's just one character.

Answer (score 2):

You want "shows" to be in a hash in order to properly iterate:

```
var shows={"shows":[        
        {"title":"Strawberry Shortcake","description":"A show about a cake","video":"none","category":"chilren"},
        {"title":"Vanilla Ice","description":"A show about a ice","video":"none","category":"adult"}
]};

var template="{{#shows}}{{.}}{{/shows}}";

var html=Mustache.render(template,shows);

document.write(html);
```

This will have the desired effect of producing your template multiple times.

**UPDATE**

To your question on Lambdas. I just looked this up in the [manual](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html). I think it covers what you were asking about:

> When the value is a callable object, such as a function or lambda, the
>   object will be invoked and passed the block of text. The text passed
>   is the literal block, unrendered. {{tags}} will not have been expanded
>   - the lambda should do that on its own. In this way you can implement filters or caching.

Template:

```
{{#wrapped}}
  {{name}} is awesome.
{{/wrapped}}
```

Hash:

```
{
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped": function() {
    return function(text) {
      return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Followup question.  Is there a way that Mustache natively supports the ability to filter results.  For example I only want to display shows where the category value is adult?

Answer (score 1):

u can do like this:

```
var shows=[        
        {"title":"Strawberry Shortcake","description":"A show about a cake","video":"none","category":"chilren"},
        {"title":"Vanilla Ice","description":"A show about a ice","video":"none","category":"adult"}
];

var template="{{#.}}title:{{title}},video:{{video}}{{/.}}";

var html=Mustache.render(template,shows);

document.write(html);
```